# how to share environment variables between shells like globals related to a master pid?

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, dynamic-linking

So, I need to share environment variables between shells, and that the changes on the variables be promptly recognized by all shells, like global variables. But they must be related to a master PID, so I can have 2 shell scripts running, each being a master with same global variable name, and it children will only change the variable related to their master PID.

I use `bash` for scripting.

*My current researches are these:*

**Modules**
I read I could use modules project for that: http://modules.sourceforge.net/, but I am having huge trouble trying to do it, it seems to lack examples? also "modules" is a too generic word, very hard to google about because mixes with many other things… after some weeks my hands are still empty…

**Simple text source file**
I read also I should use a simple text file to store/update/read variables from, as a source script file, using `flock` too to avoid concurrent writing. But there are problems related to doing that, like concurrent change of variable simultaneously by 2 shells.

**Alternatively**
I am aware that after a "global" variable is read by the shell, it will keep that value until another read is made; and another shell may change it in the mean while too…
May be a very fast external application could provide such storage and we would not try to use environment variables as globals then? but my guess is any SQL solution will be too slow…

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Environment variables are per-process, so if you want system-wide values, you're using the wrong tool. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a master script that spawns 5 child scripts with xterm, each doing different but related tasks; they all need to know what is going-on on the master script, or even on each other, and also be able to report back, or prepare something to the master if needed.

Comment: Ok, environment variables are completely the wrong tool for that. You should probably be using something that is intended for interprocess communication, such as pipes. Either have the master process broadcast changes to the children (but behave of blocking if the children don't respond), or have the children periodically query the master for updates. A file watched by inotify may also be an option. Or maybe you should have a single program that outputs to all the different terminals.

Comment: Why do you need concurrent writing?  What is wrong with one process waiting a few milliseconds for the other to finish updating the file?

Comment: @psusi flock or using `ln -s realfile lockfile` fail exit status will just do what you said "wait a few mili ...", without lock they wont wait on trying to update; but that concurrent update attempt has a flaw; one process may overwrite other process latest update, I still need to prepare a test case to work on it...

Comment: Yes... so the question was what is wrong with using the lock?

Answer (score 5):

You can write the environment to a file with `export -p` and read it back periodically in the other instances with `.` (the include command). But as you note, if there are concurrent modifications, the result won't be pretty.

If you want modifications to propagate instantly, you'll have to use a wrapper around the `export` builtin that also propagates the changes to the other shells. On Linux, you can use the `flock` utility.

```
global_export () {
  {
    flock 0
    . /path/to/env
    [ $# -eq 0 ] || export "$@"
    export -p >/path/to/env
  } </path/to/env
}
```

Note that you'll need to call `global_export` whenever you assign a new value to an exported variable.

This is rather clumsy. It's likely that there's a better way to solve your problem. The most obvious way is to have whatever command is using those environment variable read a configuration files instead.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to just using `flock` from Giles' answer, I'd do something similar to the following:

Register a signal handler to reload the file:

```
reload_env() {
 flock -s 3
 . /path/to/env
 flock -u 3
}
trap reload_env USR1
```

A function to write out the file, and send a `SIGUSR1` to all the shells notifying them to reload the file:

```
export_env() {
 flock 3
 export -p >/path/to/env
 flock -u 3
 fuser -k -USR1 /path/to/env
}
```

Open the file, but do nothing with it. This is just so that the `fuser` will be able to signal this shell:

```
exec 3>>/path/to/env
```

---

The order is somewhat important. At least the `exec ...` part must be after the `trap ...` part. Otherwise we could open the file and then get signaled by the `fuser` call before we've registered our signal handler.

*NOTE: Code is completely untested, but the principle stands.*
*NOTE2: This example code is targeted at bash.*

Comment: interesting, so wherever the code is executing, that trapped signal will be executed promptly, updating the environment variables! I think in a code that for any reason depends that the env var value be the same it was in the beggining of the function, may cause some trouble tho.. but, instead of that, a boolean could be set with your code, to require the env vars to be loaded in a safe point of the code (like the end of a loop); will have the same result; I must give a try on that, thx!

Answer (score 3):

With the `fish` shell, use *universally scoped variables*:

```
set -U var value
```

Of course, that only works across `fish` shells run by the same user.

If you want to tie it to a *master pid*, include it in the variable name

```
set -U m${masterpid}var value
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point you to *named pipes* for this purpose.
Here is [one neat example](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash) to consider.

Named pipes are created by the command:

```
mkfifo pipe_name
```

You can simply write to it by:

```
echo "This text goes to the pipe" > pipe_name
```

On the other hand, you can read from the pipe as:

```
read line < pipe_name;
echo $line
```

You can create several pipes based on how many shells do you want them to communicate. The good things about pipes is that they are not just variables. You can actually pass *any* data between the processes. You can pass whole files, lines of texts, whatever you wish.
I believe, with this in mind, you can simplify your scripts a lot. I can imagine, if your variables point to a location of data, or a file, and the other script will have to read or retrieve it, you can directly pass the data/file without even needing a variable.

Comment: cool! interesting how the 1st terminal waited I issue the read command on the other. What I see initially is that this is a "one to one" communication, and it freezes the 1st terminal until the 2nd reads the pipe, and also I need a "Many to Many" communication (many can read, many can write, simultaneously but synchronized); but indeed this new knowledge can be useful thx!

Answer (score 1):

If ksh93 is an option, there is definitely a way to implement what you want with getter and setter discipline functions that would retrieve/store the variable value from/to a shared storage.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726293/environment-variables-to-be-used-across-multiple-korn-ksh93-shell-scripts-get for details

Unlike the otherwise useful `fish` universal variables feature, you have access to the implementation so you can restrict the value sharing to a group of processes, linked to a master pid through some mechanism in your use case, while keeping a single name to the variable.

Comment: that is very interesting as I saw, you just redirect the way it set and get the variable value; indeed I didnt restrict for bash... well, good now I know about it; I wonder if bash could have something similar some day..

Comment: It might eventually. Discipline functions are in the `bash` wish list. `bash` uses to pick later features `ksh` first implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There is also this project [ScriptEchoColor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scriptechocolor/):

It can auto create, and manage for you, a DB text file. On the first run script the BD file will be created, the other scripts will symlink to that file as their own DB to manipulate variables values, and so, both can exchange information.

A simple sharing example with these files there at [examples folder](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.examples/): secExplShareEnvVarsA.sh, secExplShareEnvVarsB.sh

And a synchronized (safe and consistent read/write) shared DB access there too: secExplSyncedShareEnvVarsA.sh, secExplSyncedShareEnvVarsB.sh

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your comments, that you want basic IPC between shell scripts.  I would just write to files (with a rename for atomicity)

```
varf=$(mktemp ./myvars.XXXXXX)
echo myvar=newval > $varf
mv -T -- $varf ./myvars
```

And have readers source ./myvars periodically.

IPC is much easier with, for example, Python and the multiprocessing module.